# WSo2 - Enterprise Integrator 6.4.0 - SNMP Listening Connector

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

NewBie here. I am struggling with adding SNMP connector to my ESB project. As per https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+SNMP+Inbound+Operations

```
    Step1) I created folders and added files to /home/repository/components/dropins 
    and  home/repository/components/libs
    Step2) I then created inbound-endpoint for SNMP in my EI editor. 
since my inbound Endpoint editor design layout looked different from wso2 tutorial i mentioned above, I copied Inbound Configuration from tutorial.
    Step3) I also went ahead and created sequence as request.xml [took code from tutorial]
```

When I deployed my Inbound EP and sequence, I am getting

```
   ERROR - GenericEventBasedListener Class org.wso2.carbon.inbound.snmp.SNMPListeningConsumer not found. Please check the required class is added to the classpath.
**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.inbound.snmp.SNMPListeningConsumer cannot be found by synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v80**
```

What else should I do to get my SNMP files in to classpath? I have restarted my server and SNMP connector is available on the Palette in EI 6.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

The above ClassNotFoundException should be a result of not having the correct classes in the OSGi layer upon server startup due to missing JAR files. The following JAR files should be available in the EI server in the corresponding folders and the server needs to be restarted.

```
org.apache.synapse.snmp.listen.class-x.x.x.jar  - <EI_HOME>/dropins
snmp4j-x.x.x.jar - <EI_HOME>/lib
```

The dropins directory should contain only the OSGi bundles and the lib directory should have the NON-OSGi bundles. Upon server startup even the NON-OSGi JAR files will be converted to OSGi with a corresponding JAR file in the dropins directory.

The best way to troubleshoot this kind of a ClassNotFoundException is to access the OSGi console of WSO2 carbon-based products. Any unsatisfied constraints of the OSGi bundle can be identified easily with a couple of commands as explained in  https://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2014/01/how-to-debug-wso2-carbon-products-using.html